# Kernel version not changing even though the new version is installed

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, yum, rpm

Recently performed software update on a RHEL 6.6 (Santiago). Noticed that kernel version is not updated to latest one that was installed.

kernel version before doing software update:

```
[root@server01 ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64
```

Below is the summary of kernel packages from yum list command:

```
[root@server01 ~]# yum list kernel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-431.11.2.el6              installed
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-504.12.2.el6              @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-504.16.2.el6              @rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
Available Packages
kernel.x86_64              2.6.32-504.23.4.el6              rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases
```

Expecting the kernel would be updated to highest version among the installed ones. But it changed as below even after couple of reboots.

```
[root@server01 ~]# uname -r
**2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64**
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Run the following: "ls /boot ; uname -a".  If the new kernel version is in /boot, check /boot/grub/grub.conf.

Comment: @Liczyrzepa Yes, the new kernel is in /boot folder. In file /boot/grub/grub.conf the kernel entries are in the following order:

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64)

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64)

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux (2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64)

Comment: ok - so what is the default set to?  My guess is that is says default=0, but you want default=1 to boot -504.16.2.  Generally, updating will place the newest kernel at the head of the list, so I'm not sure what happened there.  Also, ATM, 2.6.32-504.23.4 is the latest.  You may want to run "yum upgrade" or "yum update" and check again.

Comment: @Liczyrzepa Thanks. changed from "default=0" to "default=1" and rebooted. Now the kernel in use has changed to the latest installed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm unable to explain why the newest kernel wasn't booting automatically, the kernel booted by GRUB is set in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` using the `default=<menu entry number>`, where counting starts at 0.  In this specific case, `default=1` will boot your desired kernel.